Uniform Integrability and Proving martingale of Poisson product process
So I have been stuck on the following question that I stumbled across in a textbook. It is trying to show the following product process is a martingale.
$$M_n = n! \prod_{k=1}^{n} X_k \ \text{where } X_{k} \sim \text{Poi}(1/k) \text{ and } X_k \text{ are independent} $$
I know I have to prove adaptedness, integrability and the martingale equality but I am struggling to show the integrability as I have the working out below that I cannot seem to bound above to prove $ \mathbb{E}|M_n| < \infty$
My working is as below,
$$
\mathbb{E}|M_n| = \mathbb{E}\left| n! \prod_{k=1}^n X_k \right| = n! \cdot  \mathbb{E} \prod_{k=1}^{n} X_k = n! \prod_{k=1}^{n} \mathbb{E} X_k = n!  \cdot (\mathbb{E} X_k)^n =\dfrac{n!}{k^n} < \  ? $$
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
However a follow up to this is also I am unsure how to determine whether M is a uniformly integrable martingale or not. I have tried using the Doob-Kolmogorov inequality but it breaks down when I have attempted to show it holds for L-1 norm.
Below is my attempt at trying to show that $M_n$ converges almost surely to a limit and thus is UI.
use the Doob-Kolmogorov Inequality for  martingales but for $p=1$,
$$ \mathbb{P}\left( \max_{k \leq n} | M_{k} - 0 | > b  \right) \leq \dfrac{\mathbb{E}|M_n|}{b} \quad \text{ for } b > 0.
$$
However we know that $\mathbb{E}|M_n| = \frac{n!}{k^n}$ therefore taking the limit of the above inequality and take $n \to \infty$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \max_{k \leq n} | M_{k} - 0 | > b \right) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\mathbb{E}|M_n|}{b} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n!}{k^n b} = 0 $$
However, I dont think it works in this case as the limit is not 0. Any help on this would be great too!

$n$ is fixed. $\dfrac{n!}{k^n} < \infty$ so $E|M_n|<\infty$. Where is your confusion?

So even for n tending to infinity it would still hold? I understand for some small cases of fixed n it makes sense but even for large ones? @geetha290krm

For martingale property you don't have to look at the limit at all. But for uniform integrability you have to do more work.

Ahh of course, I have also added the other part and my attempt at its working out @geetha290krm would you care to have a look at it and provide some guidance!

$EX_k=(1/k)^{n}$ is also wrong.

Any non-negative martingale converges a.s.

Ahh i see as each X in the sequence comes from a different distribution got it! Also I will likely need to prove that fact of non-negative martingales converge a.s, is there a theorem that this derives from?

That is a basic theorem, and it can be found in any book that deals with Martinagle Theory, in particular, K L Chung's book.

Ahh thanks for that I ended up gettting $ E|M| = 1$ so clearly it is finite!

But just to add how would I go about showing the limit that this sequence approaches? I understand that it would a.s but not sure how to go about finding this limit. @geetha290krm

$E(M_{n})=n!E(\prod_{k=1}^{n}X_{k})=n!\prod_{k=1}^{n}E(X_{k})=n!\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{n!}{n!}=1$. The expectation of a martingale cannot vary with $n$, it has to be constant. $X_{k}$'s are not iid and they are only independent. So it's not $(E(X_{k}))^{n}$.

Thanks @Mr.GandalfSauron also, would you be able to help me on how I might prove that this sequence $M_n$ converges almost surely? I am kinda stuck anything would be appreciated!

In particular, you have that $E(M_{n}|M_{n-1})=n!\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}X_{k}\bigg)E(X_{n}|M_{n-1})=n!\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}X_{k}\bigg)\frac{1}{n}=(n-1)!M_{n-1}$ which proves that it is a martingale.

$E(M_{n})=n!E(\prod_{k=1}^{n}X_{k})=n!\prod_{k=1}^{n}E(X_{k})=n!\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{n!}{n!}=1$. The expectation of a martingale cannot vary with $n$, it has to be constant. $X_{k}$'s are not iid and they are only independent.
In particular, you have that $E(M_{n}|M_{n-1})=n!\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}X_{k}\bigg)E(X_{n}|M_{n-1})=n!\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}X_{k}\bigg)\frac{1}{n}=(n-1)!M_{n-1}$ which proves that it is a martingale.
Now see that $M_{n}$ is a positive martingale which immediately proves that $M_{n}$ converges almost surely to an integrable random variable due to the Martingale Convergence Theorem. See Durrett, Theorem 4.2.12 for a proof of this fact. If you know about the Martingale Convergence Theorem which is proved using Doob's uprcossing inequality, you directly have that any positive supermartingale converges almost surely to an integrable random variable.
Notice that $P(M_{n}>\epsilon)\leq P(M_{n}>0)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-e^{-1/k})\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$. Thus, we have that $M_{n}\xrightarrow{P} 0$. And as we already had almost sure convergence, you have that $M_{n}$ converges almost surely to $0$.
Note that this directly shows you that you cannot have $L^{1}$ convergence and hence also you cannot have uniform integrability.
Suppose for the sake of contradiction $M_{n}$ was uniformly integrable. Then, as it converges almost surely to $0$, you have that $M_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}0$. But this is not possible as $\lim_{n\to\infty}E(M_{n})=1\neq 0$.  Hence, $M_{n}$ is not uniformly integrable and nor is it convergent/Cauchy in $L^{1}$
Well, the intuitive thing to note is that for $M_{n}$ to be positive, each term has to be non-zero. And that happens with very low probability.
NOTE: Uniform Integrability is not a necessary condition for the almost sure convergence of the martingale. Infact, uniform integrability only holds if you have convergence in $L^{1}$ of the martingale. The Martingale convergence theroem gives you almost sure convergence.

Also what do we do to find the limit it converges to? and to show L1 norm convergence? @Mr.Gandalf Sauron

@jjjcjjj893 Why don't you revise the definitions of a martingale and supermartingales again. A martingale is automatically a supermartingale.

@jjjcjjj893 What is it that you want to prove? Do you want to show almost sure convergence or $L^{1}$ convergence. In the latter case, you need to show uniform integrability which need not even hold. For example, notice that the variance of $M_{n}$ is unbounded. Secondly, even if you have almost sure or $L^{1}$ convergence, the limit need not be easy to evaluate.

I just want to find the value that $M_n$ converges to. I see that the variance is unbounded as it equals n! which tends to $\infty$ but also I need to determine whether it is UI as well. @Mr.Gandalf Sauron

Here is my proof for the UI of $M_n$, all we need to show is sup$EM_{n}^2 < \infty$. Where $EM_{n}^2 = 1$ after computation so $M_n$ is UI. So I am just stuck on the limit it converges to a.s.

@jjjcjjj893 Where is your proof? By the unbounded variance, I meant that, usually, showing bounded variance is the most useful and doable ways to show uniform integrability. Since it is unbounded, I doubt that it is uniformly integrable.

Var$M_n$ = Var $ n! \prod_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}$ = $(n!)^2 \prod_{k=1}^{n}$ Var $X_{k}$ = $(n!)^2 \times \dfrac{1}{n!} = n!$ and this tends to infinity

@jjjcjjj893 And how is that a proof of uniform integrability exactly? You are just showing that the variance is unbounded which is true.

In my class we were showed a method that if we can show for a convex function, which I used $x^2$ that sup$\mathbb{E}f(|X|) < \infty$ then X is UI. Its funny however becuase I am getting two conflicting results, unbounded variance but seemingly UI through this argument.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

How can it converge almost surely to the same limit in probability. The implication is only one right? Conv in A.s -> Conv in prob, but not the other way so how can we conclude it goes to 0 @Mr.Gandalf Sauron

@jjjcjjj893 this is the way you should think. Say it converges a.s. to some limit X. Then since you know that convergence a.s. implies convergence in probability, you have that it converges in probability to X. But you have shown that it converges in probability to 0. Then what can X be? Is the limit for convergence in probability an unique random variable? If so then can X be anything other than 0?
